# Full Image not loading on ImageView inside UICollectionView Cell Swift 4

Tags: ios, uiimageview, swift4, uicollectionviewcell, autoresize

I used Autoresizing to make proper size of image for all devices . Inside UICollectionView cell put a UIView. Over UIView I placed one ImageView with equal width of view and another view with some content. Now I use Autoresize for all devices But the size of image got differ for iPhone 6s Plus and iPad .I changes with all contents Mode but it remains same. My code for CollectionViewLayout given below.

```
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if collectionView == collection || collectionView == collection_favourite{


            return CGSize(width: display_width / 2, height: 290)

        }

    }
```

As I used Debug view hierarchy it seems that my ImageView resize exactly that I want(shown into below image with blue shade is my imageView) but image shown over it got deflected, or not showing properly .I don't have an idea how to deal with it ,I make so many changes but not resolve .Please help to get this .Thanks in advance

[image]

Here are the screen shot of my storyboard

[image]

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: try your uiimageview content mode to aspect fit.

Comment: What is display_width ?

Comment: Can you share the storyboard/ XIB screenshot for collection view Cell?

Comment: @Hardik Thakkar my display width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

Comment: @Mr. Tann I tried that , Not working

Comment: i think it is issue related to width (display_width / 2) try this way or check constrains given to imageview for that cell

Comment: @Febin I update screen shot of my storyboard

Comment: @Hardik not working, But thanks for reply

Comment: Are you using constrains or AutoResizing ? 3rd number screenshot the constraints  of image view is given using AutoResizing and it is very old way.

Comment: I mentioned above that I used Autoresizing.

Comment: Please use Constrains may be it solve issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176102/discussion-between-waliyan-and-hardik-thakkar).

Answer (score 0):

What is the Content mode of the UIImageview? Are you calling layoutIfNeeded in cellForItemAtIndexPath?

Comment: or you should set hugging of UIImageview less than UIView then set clipsTobounds property yes. I hope this workaround would help you.

Comment: I used Scale to fill content mode and also tried other modes . And I also check as per your above comment but its not working.

Comment: I have no idea about LayoutIfNeeded . Share some info or code to use it with collection view, its cell, view, image view .

Comment: As per your description UIimageview size is correct but the problem is with UIimage right? Can you set background color of Uiimageview to red or some other color just to confirm that the size is proper.
If size of UIImageview is coming differ set the Size constant just to debug this issue.
If these are ok 
Set clips to bounds to yes of Uiimageview in cellForRow
Try these steps , you will reach out to the reason of the issue.

Comment: Yes, problem with the image not imageView and also I tried with change the color of image view and constant its size but issue remain same but find something that the image is showing with the fixed height and width as I set for the imageView with the storyboard.

Comment: Please send me code of How are you getting the UIimage and setting it on the UIimageview.

Comment: I used lazyImage third party library to load image asynchronously and also check their code for content mode and clips to bound nothing to change it and its code is like below.                                                                                              let url = data.banner_url,
lazyImage.showWithSpinner(imageView:cell.cell_img, url: url)

Comment: And also check with to change the third party (FLImageView) and also tried with simply used the direct code .Not worked

Comment: Set the UIimageview content mode and clips to bound property programatically in the itemForRowAtIndex. Try some statics images on the cell to check how they are showing.